# Showing that a relation defined on a vector space is a partial order

Tags: solution-verification, order-theory

The following question is taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

Exercise: Let $X$ be a vector space.  For $x,y\in X$ define $x\leq y$ to mean there exists $\lambda \geq 1$ with with $\lambda \cdot x=y.$  Show that $(X,\leq)$ is a poset. Show that, when vector spaces are considered as posets in this way, linear maps are order preserving.

I am trying to show that $(X,\leq)$ is a poset.

For the case of reflexivity, we have $\lambda \cdot x=x.$ iff $\lambda = 1$

For transitivity, suppose $\lambda_1 \cdot x=y.$ and $\lambda_2 \cdot y=z,$ for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq 1,$ then $\lambda_2\lambda_1  \cdot x=\lambda_2 \cdot y=z.$  Hence $\lambda_2\lambda_1  \cdot x =z.$ where $\lambda_2\lambda_1\geq 1.$

For antisymmetry, suppose $\lambda_1\cdot x=y$ and $\lambda_2\cdot y=x,$  then $\lambda_2\lambda_1  \cdot x=\lambda_2 \cdot y=x$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2  \cdot y=\lambda_2 \cdot x=y.$  Since $\lambda_1\lambda_2=\lambda_2\lambda_1=1$, and both $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \geq 1$, then $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1.$  So let $\lambda=\lambda_1=\lambda_2\geq 1.$  We then have ${\lambda}^2 \cdot x=x,{\lambda}^2 \cdot y=y.$ and we get ${\lambda}^2=1$ and hence $\lambda=1$.  But $\lambda_1 \cdot x=\lambda_2 \cdot y$ and so $x=y.$

Comment: It only works for vector spaces over $\mathbb Q, \mathbb R$ or some other ordered field, and not vector spaces over $\mathbb C$ or fields of finite characteristic.

Comment: For the last case, it is possible for $\lambda_1\lambda_2\leq 1$ for one particular $x,$ $x=0,$ but then $y=0$ also.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews otherwise, is my proof correct?  The authors did not specific what field the vector space $X$ is defined over.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it is assumed that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are both $\geq 1$.  So how does one get $\lambda_1\lambda_2\leq  1$?

Comment: Some books assume one field, and in category theory, often the vector spaces over different fields are considered different categories.

Comment: Your conclusion that $\lambda_1\lambda_2=\lambda_2\lambda_1$ doesn't allow you to conclude $\lambda_1=\lambda_2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I am assuming the commutativity of multiplication here?  I mean you are right it only works over the rational and the reals.

Comment: Commutativity is fine. $2\cdot 3=3\cdot 2$ does not imply $3=2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I fixed my solution, can you check if it is correct please.